# Sort custom objects by String and alphanumeric

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of objects and I want to make alphanumeric asc sorting by name. I'm using SAP Hybris and java 11.

```
   public class TestSort{
 
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String lenghtDimension;
    private String widthDimension;
    private String thicknessDimension;
    //code
   }

    List<TestSort> objects = new ArrayList<>();
   

    Collections.sort(getAllobjects(), (O1,O2) -> O1.getName().compareTo(O2.getName()));
```

But I have the following result

```
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 S"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 T"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2700 T"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 3000 T"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 900 x 1800 T"
   "GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2400 T"
   "GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2700 T"
   "GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T"
```

And the results I should have is :

```
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 900 x 1800 T"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 S"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 T"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2700 T"
   "GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 3000 T"
   "GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T"
   "GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2400 T"
   "GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2700 T"
```

I need a generic solution because the name can be in another format.

UPDATE :

The name contain 15 x 1200 x 2700 , lenghtDimension x widthDimension X thicknessDimension

Comment: Why do you expect `900 x 1800` to come before `1200 x 3000`? The string-sorting is lexicographical and `1` comes before `9` in the alphabet. Thats why it sorts like that. Do you actually want to interpret the numbers as numbers and sort them ascending instead of lexicographical? This will be quite difficult if you only have the data as text, since you will have to extract the numbers and parse them.

Comment: You're going to have to break the dimension string into pieces to be able to sort it by dimension.

Comment: @Zabuzard, I updated my code I modified my code, my model contains the dimensions
And the name is made up of name and dimensions

Comment: You will have to split the string into its individual sections, parse them as actual numbers and go for a much more advanced `Comparator` that combines all of that.

Comment: As first step, do you actually have to take all of the data as `String`? On the level of your class, cant you have it as `double length; int width; int thickness;`? Would be much easier then.

Comment: Please put more effort into carefully drafting your Question *before* posting. Your edits with additional details now make the previously posted [smart correct Answer by oleg.cherednik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575287/642706) look obtuse or even incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write a custom comparator using a [regular expressions](https://regex101.com/r/JmGtTh/1):

```java
public static class Data {

    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    public Data(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

}

public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2700 T", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 T", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 3000 T", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 12.5 x 900 x 1800 T", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 S", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2400 T", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2700 T", "Description"));
    data.add(new Data("GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T", "Description"));

    Comparator<Data> sortByName = new Comparator<>() {
        private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s])+\\s+([^\\s])+\\s+" +
                "([^\\s])+\\s+(?<length>[^\\s]+)\\sx\\s+(?<width>[^\\s]+)\\s+" +
                "x\\s+(?<thickness>[^\\s]+)\\s+([^\\s]+)");

        @Override
        public int compare(Data one, Data two) {
            Matcher matcherOne = pattern.matcher(one.name);
            Matcher matcherTwo = pattern.matcher(two.name);
            boolean matchOne = matcherOne.matches();
            boolean matchTwo = matcherTwo.matches();

            if (!matchOne || !matchTwo)
                return 0;

            int res = compareString(matcherOne, matcherTwo, 1);
            res = res != 0 ? res : compareString(matcherOne, matcherTwo, 2);
            res = res != 0 ? res : compareString(matcherOne, matcherTwo, 3);
            res = res != 0 ? res : compareDouble(matcherOne, matcherTwo, "length");
            res = res != 0 ? res : compareDouble(matcherOne, matcherTwo, "width");
            res = res != 0 ? res : compareDouble(matcherOne, matcherTwo, "thickness");
            res = res != 0 ? res : compareString(matcherOne, matcherTwo, 7);

            return res;
        }

        private int compareDouble(Matcher one, Matcher two, String group) {
            double a = Double.parseDouble(one.group(group));
            double b = Double.parseDouble(two.group(group));
            return Double.compare(a, b);
        }

        private int compareString(Matcher one, Matcher two, int group) {
            String a = one.group(group);
            String b = two.group(group);
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    };

    data.forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.name));
    data.sort(sortByName);
    System.out.println();
    data.forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.name));
}
```

**Output**

```
GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2700 T
GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 3000 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 900 x 1800 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 S
GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2400 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2700 T
GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T

GGGG F B 12.5 x 900 x 1800 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 S
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2400 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 2700 T
GGGG F B 12.5 x 1200 x 3000 T
GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T
GGGG F B 15 x 900 x 1800 T
GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2400 T
GGGG F B 15 x 1200 x 2700 T
```